# Wicket + jsTree, links generation in ajax response

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, jstree

I'm using jsTree jQuery plugin for drawing a tree. 
When user clicks a node, an ajax request containing node's id is send to server.

In my response I generating such piece of html (this is done in separate servlet):

```
<li id="node_id_1"><a href="foobar">Child item 1</a></li>
<li id="node_id_2"><a href="foobar">Child item 2</a></li>
<li id="node_id_3"><a href="foobar">Child item 3</a></li>
<li id="node_id_4"><a href="foobar">Child item 4</a></li>
<li id="node_id_5"><a href="foobar">Child item 5</a></li>
```

And this items are drawn under the selected node.

The question is: what value should I use for href attribute for referring wicket pages? I.e. I need links pointing to class MainPage with some parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a [RepeatingView](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/repeater/RepeatingView.html) or [ListView](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/list/ListView.html) that returns some [BookmarkablePageLink](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/BookmarkablePageLink.html) objects:

Here is a Sample component:

```
public class JsTree extends Panel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JsTree(final String id, final IModel<List<MyDomainObject>> model){
        super(id);
        this.add(new ListView<MyDomainObject>("list", model){

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem<MyDomainObject> item){
                MyDomainObject modelObject = item.getModelObject();
                final Map<String, String> params =
                    Collections.singletonMap("id", modelObject
                        .getObjectId());
                item.add(
                    new BookmarkablePageLink<Void>(
                        "link", MyPage.class,
                        new PageParameters(params)
                    ).add(new Label("label",modelObject.getName()))
                ).setOutputMarkupId(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the corresponding HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<wicket:head></wicket:head>
<wicket:panel>
    <ul class="jsTree">
        <li wicket:id="list">
            <a href="#" wicket:id="link">
                <wicket:container wicket:id="label" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

I've used a `MyDomainObject` type that just has an id and a name. The name is displayed, the id is linked to. Basically you can add any serializeable parameter to a `BookmarkablePageLink` and then parse the parameter from the page you link to using the [Page.getPageParameters()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/Page.html#getPageParameters%28%29) method.